# Create ref to sub document's array for each property of subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Model **A** looks like

```
    { a : {
     step1: [{
        type: { type: String },
        category: { type: String },
       }],
     step2: [{
        type: { type: String },
        category: { type: String },
       }]
    } }
```

Model **B** which I wanted to create should contain a prop which will ref to Model A.step1  or A.step2 , trying to acheive this by following

```
    { progress : [
         {
           step: {
              type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "A.a.{What should be here}",
              required: true,
           },
           details: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed },
         }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create Schemas for all of them :)

I would just separate the three completely - not sure if this is viable to you as the whole idea behind this is a bit mysterious, but would something like this work for you?

```
const stepSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    category: String,
});
const Step = mongoose.model("steps", stepSchema);


const aSchema = new Schema({
    step1: [stepSchema],
    step2: [stepSchema],
});
const A = mongoose.model("as", aSchema);


const progressSchema = new Schema({
    a: { type: aSchema, required: true, ref: "as"},
    progress: [{ type: stepSchema, required: true, ref: "steps" }],
    details: Schema.Types.Mixed,
});
const Progress = mongoose.model("progresses", aSchema);
```